# Kendo-Knockout: Closing window breaks bindings

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

I am using RPNiemeyer`s kendo-knockout library. I have a button which onclick instantiates a javascript object, binds a div to that object and opens a pop up window. When I close the window from the x button which is in the top right corner (I have not imported the images and it is not visualized correctly in the fiddle.), the bindings are broken and the button does not open the window again. Here is my html:

```
<button onclick="openPopUp()">OpenPopUp</button>

<div id="productionStates" class="hidden">
    <div data-bind="kendoWindow: { isOpen: isOpen, title:'States', center:true, width: 600, height: 150, modal: true, resizable: false, actions: ['Maximize', 'Close'] }" >
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Change state:</legend>
            <table>
                <tr data-bind="foreach: productionStates">
                    <td><button class="k-button" data-bind="value: ProductionState, text: ProductionState" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

</div>
```

javascript:

```
var ProductionStatesList = function() {
    var
        self = this;

    ProductionStatesList.prototype.productionStates =
        ko.observableArray([ { ProductionState: ko.observable("Pending") } ]);

        ProductionStatesList.prototype.openPopUp = function () {
            self.isOpen(true);
        };     

        ProductionStatesList.prototype.isOpen = ko.observable(false);
        ProductionStatesList.prototype.openPopUp = function () {
                    self.isOpen(true);                    
                };
        ProductionStatesList.prototype.close = function () {
            self.isOpen(false);
        }
};
    var elementIsBound = function (elementId) {
                return !!ko.dataFor(document.getElementById(elementId));
            };

    var openPopUp = function(){
        var productionStatesList = new ProductionStatesList();
        if (!elementIsBound("productionStates")){
            ko.applyBindings(productionStatesList, document.getElementById("productionStates"));
        }

        productionStatesList.openPopUp();
    }
```

Here is the code in jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5Zkyg/40/

Steps to reproduce:

1.Click the button. Pop up window is opened.

2.Close the window from  the top right image (the x button not visualized because images are not imported).

Please explain the reason why this does not work and any solution will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that subsequent calls to `openPopup` are creating a new instance of a `ProductionStatesList` and calling `openPopup` on it, while the element's are bound to the original instance.

One solution would be to create your instance outside of the function like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/bZF9k/

Otherwise, if you have an array of `ProductionStatesList` instance and want to manage the whole thing with Knockout, then you would probably want to create a `selectedProductionStatesList` observable and use the `with` binding around the area inside the window, so that it is rebound each time.

Comment: Unfortunately, the first solution want work for my case. Is it possible to show some example of your second proposal in fiddle. Thanks.

Comment: I refactored my code to create the instance outside the function. The problem is that the instance depends on another object and I used to pass that object in the constructor of the instance. So now I initialize ProductionStatesList with empty constructor and call explicitly initialize method with the dependent object as a parameter, every time I call the openPopUp function. Maybe it is not the best solution but it is the best that works for me in this case and I will leave it that way for now. Thank You again! Your feedback is priceless.

Comment: OK- if something still is working let me know or get it in a fiddle!