# Kendo-Knockout: bindings break when changing the value of the bind element

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

I will use the code of previously asked question with minor changes but the case is different:

[Kendo-Knockout: Closing window breaks bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884348/kendo-knockout-closing-window-breaks-bindings)

HTML:

```
<button onclick="openPopUp()">OpenPopUp</button>

<div id="productionStates" class="hidden">
    <div data-bind="kendoWindow: { isOpen: isOpen, title:'States', center:true, width: 600, height: 150, modal: true, resizable: false, actions: ['Maximize', 'Close'] }" >
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Change state:</legend>
            <table>
                <tr data-bind="foreach: productionStates">
                    <td><button class="k-button" data-bind="value: ProductionState, text: ProductionState" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

</div>
```

javascript:

```
    var ProductionStatesList = function() {
    var self = this;

    ProductionStatesList.prototype.productionStates = 
        ko.observableArray([ { ProductionState: ko.observable("Pending") } ]);

        ProductionStatesList.prototype.openPopUp = function () {
            self.isOpen(true);
        };     

        ProductionStatesList.prototype.isOpen = ko.observable(false);

        ProductionStatesList.prototype.close = function () {
            self.isOpen(false);
        }
};
    var elementIsBound = function (elementId) {
                return !!ko.dataFor(document.getElementById(elementId));
            };


    var myProductionStatesList = ko.observable();
    var openPopUp = function(){
        myProductionStatesList(new ProductionStatesList()); 
        if (!elementIsBound("productionStates")){
            ko.applyBindings(myProductionStatesList, document.getElementById("productionStates"));
        }

        myProductionStatesList().openPopUp(); 
    }
```

`myProductionStatesList`  is an observable. On click of the button pop up is opened and I am instantiating the `ProductionStatesList` view model and assigning its value to `myProductionStatesList`. The first time the button is clicked everyting works fine. When You close the pop up and click the button again the bindings are broken and nothing happens. I am expecting on every click of the button the new instance of the ProductionStatesList to be rebound as `myProductionStatesList`  is an observable. What am I missing?

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bZF9k/15/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your best bet in this case is to get to a point where you do not need to call `ko.applyBindings` multiple times.

A decent choice would be to create a view model that has an observable to hold your current `ProductionStatesList` and your `openPopup` function.  Then, use the `with` binding around your editor.

The view model could just look like:

```
var viewModel = {
    myProductionStatesList: ko.observable(),
    openPopup: function() {
       var newList = new ProductionStatesList();
       this.myProductionStatesList(newList);
       newList.openPopup();
    }
};
```

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/wBCdK/